# How to configure SSL termination on Nginx with a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I get my SSL request through a load balancer which is performing SSL termination and sending the decrypted traffic to my server on port 81.

I'm running Nginx and have setup a listener to the port 81 and I would like to tell my Rails app that this is a SSL request.

Here is how my Nginx config looks like:

```
  server {
    listen 81;

    server_name SERVER;

    root /var/www/app/current/public;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;

    passenger_enabled on;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

      location / {

        passenger_enabled on;

        proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;

      }

  }
```

It goes through but Ruby on Rails doesn't detect the header request.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto'], so it takes the request as non-https.
What should I add in order to get Rails thinking this is a SSL request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So proxy_set_header is not used by passenger, you need to use passenger_set_cgi_param instead:

```
passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
```

Answer (score -1):

The nginx directive passenger_set_cgi_param has been replaced by passenger_set_env.
 https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerEnvVar

for newer nginx the directive should be

```
passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
```